# Eclipse IDE split bottom panel to two like in visual studio

Tags: eclipse, user-interface

I have this bottom panel with many "Views" (tabs like "Console" and "Debug").
They all reside as tabs next to each other in the same container.
I'd like to split it to two - it's possible in Visual Studio.

Here's how it looks like now:
[image]

There's a lot of space wasted in the right side as you can see and it would make it a lot easier for me if I could just split this container/panel to two, so some tabs in the left side and some in the right.

For example, I'd like to split the above like this:
Left:

- Console
- Development Mode
- Breakpoints
- Servers

Right:

- Debug
- Variables
- Search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply grab one of the tabs (like Servers) and drag it towards the left hand side of the stack.  You should see rectangle outlines of where the view will go when you drop it.  Once you've created another stack to the left, simply drag the other views you want over there and drop them (next to the Servers tab).